# Template / Generic user-defined classes in python weird behavior

Tags: python, types, constructor, mypy

When I write the following code, mypy issues an error (like it should):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List
Data = TypeVar("Data")
class State(Generic[Data]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.d: Data = 8.9
s = State[int]()
```

When I remove the (completely redundant, right?) `-> None` part from the ctor, `mypy` *ignores* the type mismatch. Why is that? (note that this is *not* a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725868/generics-templates-in-python))

Comment: The `-> None` is not redundant at all! No return annotation means: don't type check this function. Use `mypy --strict` always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mypy only checks functions that are typed. By removing the `-> None` you are making your `__init__` untyped and therefore mypy doesn't check that function.

This is covered in the common issues section of the mypy wiki: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#no-errors-reported-for-obviously-wrong-code

> There are several common reasons why obviously wrong code is not flagged as an error.
>
> The function containing the error is not annotated. Functions that do not have any annotations (neither for any argument nor for the return type) are not type-checked, and even the most blatant type errors (e.g. `2 + 'a'`) pass silently. The solution is to add annotations. Where that isn’t possible, functions without annotations can be checked using `--check-untyped-defs`.